# GitVersion Nuget version to include sha

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, gitversion

in short:
I'm trying to format my NugetVersion instead of using the default, by adding -{ShortSha} in the end (to versions with prefix)

So basically what I'm trying to do is to use [GitVersionTask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersionTask/) Nuget package to version my Nuget packages **but also including ShortSha in the end when a prefix is available** , the main reason for that is so I can tell exactly from which commit that package was created.

I managed to make default versioning working by simply adding :

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="GitVersionTask" Version="5.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

to my ".csproj" file.

now when packing my packages, they do get a cool version such as:

**0.1.0-testgitversion0026**

which is awesome, but I would like to also add the commit short sha to it so it becomes:

**0.1.0-testgitversion0026-6448d7b**

looking at the [docs](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/), by editing the GitVersion.yml it seems that I could change InformationalVersion, FileVersion, AssemblyVersion
using: assembly-versioning-format, assembly-versioning-format, assembly-informational-format

unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to change NugetVersion format through GitVersion.yml

**Is there a way to format NugetVersion in GitVersionTask?**

**Or do I have to use code or another approach instead of [GitVersionTask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersionTask/)?**

Note: I would like to add this short sha only when there's a prefix

thank you for your help, it is really appreciated.